# Deal with many commnadline options in c++

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a c++ program whose main function looks something like this:

```
if(a.size == 2) {
    if(s1) {
        f1(a[0], a[1], "string1");
    }
    else{
        f1(a[0], a[1], "string2");
    }
}
if(a.size == 1) {
    if(s1) {
        f1(a[0], "string1");
    }
    else{
        f1(a[0], "string2");
    }
}
else {
    if(s1) {
        f1("string1");
    }
    else{
        f1("string2");
    }
}
...
...
...
...
```

where `a` and `s1` are received from commandline options.
It has many commandline options and many layers of `if...else..` structures and looks even messier.
Is there a way to improve?

Comment: have a look on boost program options http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: I'd recommend using [boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: It seems as if you already have code that parses all the command-line options and deposits its results in variables like `a` and `s1`. Do you want to redesign/replace the code that produces these variables, or do you just want a neater way to process the data that have already been placed in these variables?

Comment: These variables are already results of the boost parser, so I am looking for a way to better processing these variable, rather than a way to getting them.

Comment: Initialize these variables to default values, then change them when the command line options say so.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this original code,

```
if(a.size == 2) {
    if(s1) {
        f1(a[0], a[1], "string1");
    }
    else{
        f1(a[0], a[1], "string2");
    }
}
if(a.size == 1) {
    if(s1) {
        f1(a[0], "string1");
    }
    else{
        f1(a[0], "string2");
    }
}
else {
    if(s1) {
        f1("string1");
    }
    else{
        f1("string2");
    }
}
```

*assuming* that there’s a missing `else`, do

```
auto const s = (s1? "string1" : "string2");
switch( a.size )
{
    case 0: f1( s ); break;
    case 1: f1( a[0], s ); break;
    case 2: f1( a[0], a[1], s ); break;
}
```

For example.

---

For the general problem of parsing command line arguments, check out `getopt` and various options parsers, e.g. in Boost.